# Keras Categorical Cross Entropy

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to wrap my head around the categorical cross entropy loss. Looking at the [implementation](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/keras/backend.py) of the cross entropy loss in Keras:

```
  # scale preds so that the class probas of each sample sum to 1
  output = output / math_ops.reduce_sum(output, axis, True)
  # Compute cross entropy from probabilities.
  epsilon_ = _constant_to_tensor(epsilon(), output.dtype.base_dtype)
  output = clip_ops.clip_by_value(output, epsilon_, 1. - epsilon_)
  return -math_ops.reduce_sum(target * math_ops.log(output), axis)
```

I do not see where the delta = output - target
is calculated.
See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945871/derivative-of-softmax-loss-function).
What am I missing?

Comment: This code computes the loss, not the gradient of the loss. Gradients are computed using automatic differentiation.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy So I can I figure out where and how it is calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confusing two different concepts / events here.

The categorical cross entropy loss is a measure of the error of your model, as calculated by :

```
def categorical_crossentropy(target, output, from_logits=False, axis=-1):
     <etc>
```

This just returns an array of losses for each label, it is the direct difference between the true label and what your model thinks the label should be.

The next step after calculating the loss (part of the forward propagation phase) is to then start backpropagation, i.e. we want to find the influence that each weight/bias matrix has on the loss you've calculated above, so that we can perform the update step.

The first step is then to calculate dL/dz i.e. the derivative of the loss function with respect to the linear function (y = Wx + b), which itself is the combination of dL/da * da/dz (i.e. the deriv loss wrt activation * deriv activation wrt the linear function).

The link [you posted](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/945871/derivative-of-softmax-loss-function/945918#945918) is the derivative of the activation function wrt the linear function. [This blog](https://medium.com/@pdquant/all-the-backpropagation-derivatives-d5275f727f60) does a decent job of explaining how all the parts fit together, although the activation function they use is a sigmoid, but the overall pieces that fit together are the same.

Comment: Thanks for your help! So as far as I understood it if I put that crossentropy code in a function and provide it to my model `model.compile(loss=CustomCrossEntropy, optimizer="adam", metrics=["accuracy"])`, the Automatic Differentiation of TensorFlow will take care of calculating the derivative for me?

Comment: Yes it will! However you don't even need to create a custom loss function if you're only using categorical cross entropy. You can just use `loss='categorical_crossentropy'`

Comment: Perfect! Categorical cross entropy is just my starting point and I want to customize it. Thanks again.